# Rings and finite union of semiclosed intervals

Tags: measure-theory

> If $R$ is the ring generated by the class of all semiclosed intervals $[a,b)$ (over the reals, $a<b$), then every set in $R$ can be expressed as a disjoint union of finitely many such intervals.

One part is easy, because there's a theorem that says that for all $A\in R$, $A$ is contained in a finite union of sets $[a,b)$. If I interpreted "contained" correctly, then $A\subset \cup_{j=1}^n [a_j,b_j)$. The intervals $[a_j,b_j)$ are not necessarily disjoint, but one can work out more or less easily that "$\cup_{j=1}^n [a_j,b_j)$" is now disjoint.

However, I don't know how to prove $\cup_{j=1}^n [a_j,b_j) \subset A$ and if this is a good strategy to prove $A= \cup_{j=1}^n [a_j,b_j)$ because, can't one has weird sets in $R$ such that $A$ is something like $[c,d)\cup \lbrace x\rbrace$ ($d<x$)?

Comment: To check: here, "ring" means a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ (for some set $X$) which is closed under binary union ($\cup$) and complement ($\setminus$), right?

Comment: Yes, yes! (had to write chars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, we need to show that two sets the same: $R$, and the set of finite disjoint unions of semiclosed intervals.

Let $S$ be this set of finite disjoint unions of semiclosed intervals, so our goals is to show that $R = S$. We'll do this by proving $R \subseteq S$ and $S \subseteq R$.

Here's a widely useful trick: if you show that $S$ is also a ring, then you get $R \subseteq S$ almost automatically! (Why?)

We also need to show $S \subseteq R$, but this is obvious because every finite disjoint union of semiclosed intervals is in particular a finite union of semiclosed intervals.

So, the only important thing is to show that $S$ is a ring. You should do this very directly, by showing that a union of two elements of $S$ is still in $S$, and likewise that the difference of two elements in $S$ is still in $S$.

Please give this a shot, and let us know if you're still stuck!

Comment: Ah, the almost part you meant that there's a minimal ring $T(R)$ such that $R\subset T(R)\subset S$, right?

Comment: Not quite -- remember that $R$ is the ring generated by all semiclosed intervals. In other words, it is the smallest ring which contains all semiclosed intervals. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you sir, you have been of great help!